# Replace InputEvent.data value

Tags: javascript

I need to replace each new character coming to the textarea. Is there any way to do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body><textarea id="ta"></textarea></body>

    <script>
        let ta = document.getElementById("ta");
        ta.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
            e.data = "some value"; // it's not working 
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

The possible solution is just to replace the target value with a new character using a selection range, but I don't want really to play with string splitting and joining. So, I'm asking for the easiest way.

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? Generaly you could have a extra state for value and pass it down to textarea and in onChange simply overwrite setValue

Comment: 1/2 ... Reading about [`InputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent), [`InputEvent.inputType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType) and [`InputEvent.data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/data) might be a good starting point ...

Comment: 2/2 ... in combination with `selectionStart` / `selectionEnd` as with e.g. [`HTMLInputElement`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) and/or [`HTMLTextAreaElement`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) one pretty much could cover/solve the OP's task.

Comment: 3/3 ... On the other hand, _"... need[ing] to replace each new character coming to the textarea ..."_, very much sounds like preserving the textarea's [`defaultValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#properties).

Comment: @ArtemZip ... Regarding the so far provided answers are there any questions left?

Comment: @PeterSeliger, the answers are great, but I already knew about that solutions, however, I thought that there is a way to override one function, which will be one lined :) 

Your comments contain a solution, which I'm using right now, however, it's huge as it causes problems when replacing a single ASCII char with Unicode one, therefore selection is broken.

Comment: @ArtemZip ... _"when replacing a single ASCII char with Unicode one, therefore selection is broken"_ ... which means that you're actually facing a totally different problem than the one you described with your question at 1st place. It is not the detection of deleted and/or replaced characters but the handling of unicode character strings. Maybe you could break down the problem to a simple executable stack snippet, thus one could carry on with solving the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach which detects changes within the input data/value might ...

- utilize a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) instance as textarea and/or input-element based ***storage*** for such an element's most recent (text) value.
- enable the exact detection of data/value-changes by keeping track of such an element's ***`'input'` event*** based on the most recent and the current (text) values as well as on `selectionEnd` and sometimes on the input event's `data` value.
- In case of having verified an input-event based text value change ***a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) is created and dispatched***. Thus one now can ***directly listen to and handle textarea and/or input-element related `'input:datachange'` events***.

On top of the new custom `'input:datachange'` event type, with all the additional information one does neither receive by `'input'` nor by `'change'` events, the OP now might be able to solve the replacement task.

```js
// the node reference based storage of most recent element values.
const mostRecentValueStorage = new WeakMap;

function getDataChangeFromDeleteOrPaste({ currentTarget, data }) {
  const recentValue = mostRecentValueStorage.get(currentTarget);
  const { value: currentValue, selectionEnd } = currentTarget;

  let deletionStart = selectionEnd;
  let leadingValue = currentValue.slice(0, deletionStart);

  while ((leadingValue !== '') && !recentValue.startsWith(leadingValue)) {
    leadingValue = leadingValue.slice(0, --deletionStart);
  }
  const deletionLength =
    (selectionEnd - deletionStart) + (recentValue.length - currentValue.length);

  const deleted = recentValue.slice(deletionStart, (deletionStart + deletionLength));

  const insertLength = currentValue.length + deleted.length - recentValue.length;
  const insertStart = selectionEnd - insertLength;

  const inserted = (insertStart < selectionEnd)
    && currentValue.slice(insertStart, selectionEnd)
    || null;

  return {
    currentValue,
    recentValue,
    deleted: (deleted === '') ? null : deleted,
    deletionStart: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionStart,
    deletionLength: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionLength,
    inserted,
    insertStart: (inserted === null) ? null : insertStart,
    insertLength: (inserted === null) ? null : insertLength,
  };
}
function getDataChangeFromInsertText({ currentTarget, data }) {
  const recentValue = mostRecentValueStorage.get(currentTarget);
  const { value: currentValue, selectionEnd } = currentTarget;

  const insertLength = data.length;

  const deletionStart = (selectionEnd - insertLength);
  const deletionLength = (recentValue.length - currentValue.length + insertLength);

  const deleted = recentValue.slice(deletionStart, (deletionStart + deletionLength));

  return {
    currentValue,
    recentValue,
    deleted: (deleted === '') ? null : deleted,
    deletionStart: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionStart,
    deletionLength: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionLength,
    inserted: data,
    insertStart: (selectionEnd - insertLength),
    insertLength,
  };
}

function handleCustomInputDataChange(evt) {
  const { currentTarget } = evt;

  if (currentTarget.value !== mostRecentValueStorage.get(currentTarget)) {
    const { data } = evt;

    const dataChange = (
      (typeof data === 'string') && getDataChangeFromInsertText(evt)
    ) || (
      (data === null) && getDataChangeFromDeleteOrPaste(evt)
    ) || null;

    // put the most recent element value into an object based storage.
    mostRecentValueStorage.set(currentTarget, currentTarget.value);

    currentTarget
      .dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('input:datachange', {
          bubbles: true,
          detail: {
            dataChange,
            inputEvent: evt,
          },
        })        
      );
  }
}

function enableCustomInputDataChangeHandling(elmNode) {
  // put the initial element value into an object based storage.
  mostRecentValueStorage.set(elmNode, elmNode.defaultValue);

  elmNode
    .addEventListener('input', handleCustomInputDataChange);
}
function initializeCustomInputDataChangeHandling() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-handle-input-data-change]')
    .forEach(enableCustomInputDataChangeHandling);
}

function main() {
  initializeCustomInputDataChangeHandling();

  document
    .addEventListener(
      'input:datachange',
      ({ target, detail: { dataChange } }) => console.log({ /*target, */dataChange })
    );
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 76%; min-height: 100%!important; }
```

```html
<textarea
  data-handle-input-data-change
  cols="16"
  rows="12"
>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ... edit text in whichever way.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

In react you would use something called a 'controlled component'.
Which looks like this:

```
const initialValue = 'hello'
const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState(initialValue)

<input
  type='text'
  value={someValue}
  onChange={() => {setSomeValue(e.target.value)} />
```

And you do could that, but then update the value before updating the input field.

```
const initialValue = 'hello'
const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState(initialValue)

// Convert the last value to a new value 
const scrambledValue = scramble(someValue)

<input
  type='text'
  value={scrambledValue}
  onChange={() => {setSomeValue(e.target.value)} />
```

To alter the value

Comment: I'm using vue.js, and for me, the onChange event is triggering my function randomly and I cannot see what is the value of change